# How to understand 思ってする in the sentence below?

Tags: parsing

> どうせ人生の一定の時間を仕事に費やすのなら、その時間が楽しいと思えるほうがいいに決まっている。それに楽しいと**思ってする**ことは、何かとスムーズに運び成果もあがるものだ。こうして好循環が生まれてくる。

Answer (score 4):

For example:

> 楽しいと思って仕事をする
> *lit.* I do the work, thinking it's fun / enjoying it

Turning it into a noun phrase using a relative clause, you get:

> 〔楽しいと思ってする〕仕事
> *lit.* the work [that I do, thinking it's fun / enjoying it]

In your example, the head noun is こと. 楽しいと思ってする is a relative clause that modifies こと.

> 〔楽しいと思ってする〕こと
> *lit.* the thing [that you do while thinking it's fun / enjoying it]

> 「それに楽しいと思ってすることは、何かとスムーズに運び成果もあがるものだ。」

"And/Also, what you enjoy doing will go smoothly and produce good results, too."